# How to use DCOUNT on select- sql query while using group by?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, dcount

How to use DCOUNT on select- sql query while using group by?

I have a problem and first, I want to show part of the real table
![I WANT a query that show me per date the amount of bl_no in feedback_status=”99” , the amount of bl_no is feedback_status=”1”

I try to wrote this code in sql query on MS ACCESS and I don’t get the result that I want

```
SELECT CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_DATE, dcount("*","M_MAAGAR_BL_CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_LOG","FEEDBACK_STATUS=0") 
FROM M_MAAGAR_BL_CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_LOG
GROUP BY CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_DATE;
```

Can you help me?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ndn.jpg)

Comment: Your query seems fine, but I think you need to add a few extra conditions. You should also add a `WHERE clause` with the feedback status you want displayed (I believe it's 99 in your case) like `WHERE feedback_status="99"`

Comment: Ideally you would take some more time to format your question as it is a bit hard to understand the big picture of the question. Additional details are always welcome, as example data and expected output of your query are most of the time required.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  The following query will give you the number of BL_NO having FEEDBACK_STATUS = '99' for each unique date.  I'm not sure why you have FEEDBACK_STATUS=0 in your query.  You might have to clarify the question if this doesn't work for you.

```
SELECT CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_DATE, COUNT(BL_NO) as Amount 
FROM M_MAAGAR_BL_CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_LOG
WHERE FEEDBACK_STATUS=99
GROUP BY CUSTOM_TRANSMISSION_DATE;
```